# HTML popup menu prevent overflow container

Tags: html, css

I have following code which show popupmenu when click on icon on each block, right now for the third block the menu overflow the black container, I need to display inside the container by shifting the menu div towards left side. Only the last column menu need to shift left for keeping the position inside the container.

How it's possible?

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 508px;
  background: black;
}

.grid_block {
  background-color: #269ad3 !important;
  color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.edit-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.edit-dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 12px 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.w3-right {
  float: right !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.w3-xlarge {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="pdf_parent_id" class="grid_container">
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu0')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu0" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu1')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu1" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu2')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu2" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu3')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu3" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/kvzbuLn9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you can do this:

```
.w3-right {
  position: relative;
}

#dropdown_menu3 {
  bottom: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

EDIT: Use this code:

```
#dropdown_menu2{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Working example:

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
      var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-dropdown-content");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
        var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
        if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
          openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.grid_container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width:508px;
    background:black;
}
.grid_block {
    background-color: #269ad3 !important;
    color: #efefef;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.edit-dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.edit-dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 12px 5px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.w3-right {
    float: right !important;
    padding:10px;
}
.w3-xlarge{
   font-size:25px;
}
 .show {display: block;}

.w3-right {
  position: relative;
}

#dropdown_menu3 {
  bottom: 30px;
  position: absolute;
}

#dropdown_menu2{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="pdf_parent_id" class="grid_container">

<div class="grid_block">
   <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
         <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu0')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
         <div id="dropdown_menu0" class="edit-dropdown-content">
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_block">
   <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
         <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu1')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
         <div id="dropdown_menu1" class="edit-dropdown-content">
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_block">
   <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
         <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu2')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
         <div id="dropdown_menu2" class="edit-dropdown-content">
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_block">
   <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
         <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu3')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
         <div id="dropdown_menu3" class="edit-dropdown-content">
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually I need the menu open towards left side, instead of scroll appearing while menu open.

Comment: @CodeDezk You mean this? https://jsfiddle.net/ycaLxuq6/1/

Answer (score 1):

If your html is static and is not generated by some js code then you can use a straightforward approach - just add additional class to your menu container:

**css**:

```
.menu-icon-container {
  position: relative;
}
.edit-dropdown-content--inside {
  right: 23px;
  top: 0;
}
```

**html**:

```
<div class="w3-right menu-icon-container">
    <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu2')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
    <div id="dropdown_menu2" class="edit-dropdown-content edit-dropdown-content--inside">
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
         <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `position: relative` on the `.grid-block` so we can then add `left: 30px` on our dropdown. This should position them all to the left.

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 508px;
  background: black;
}

.grid_block {
  background-color: #269ad3 !important;
  color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
}

.edit-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  left: 30px;
  min-width: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.edit-dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 12px 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.w3-right {
  float: right !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.w3-xlarge {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="pdf_parent_id" class="grid_container">
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu0')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu0" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu1')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu1" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu2')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu2" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu3')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu3" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

We can also use the `nth-child` selector to target only the one at the end of the row.

```js
function myFunction(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("edit-dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.grid_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 150px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 508px;
  background: black;
}

.grid_block {
  background-color: #269ad3 !important;
  color: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
}

.edit-dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  left: 120px;
  min-width: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.grid_block:nth-child(3n) .edit-dropdown-content {
  left: 30px;
}

.edit-dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 12px 5px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.w3-right {
  float: right !important;
  padding: 10px;
}

.w3-xlarge {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="pdf_parent_id" class="grid_container">
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu0')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu0" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu1')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu1" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu2')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu2" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid_block">
    <div>
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
      <h6 style="font-size:12px;">Subtitle</h6>
      <div class="w3-right">
        <i onclick="myFunction('dropdown_menu3')" class="dropbtn fa fa-ellipsis-v w3-xlarge"></i>
        <div id="dropdown_menu3" class="edit-dropdown-content">
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Menu1</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Menu2</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Menu3</a>
          <a class="contextMenu"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Menu4</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```